# C# What integer value of array.length

Tags: c#, arrays

Say I have an array with size 20. Is that array's `.length` property equivalent to 20? Also is there a way in my code to convert `array.length` to an integer?

Comment: array.length is already an integer and yes the array.length will be 20

Comment: can i favourite your answer?, and also when i try to do MessageBox.Show(files.Length); my line of code gets underlined red.

Comment: you could research a bit more. this is the first result on google when searching "array.length" c# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No you can't and I wouldn't call it an answer, it's barley a comment :)

Comment: Surely it would have been quicker and easier to search for the answer yourself than it would be to post a question on SO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. According to the MSDN docs, an array's `.Length` property returns the total number of elements in all the dimensions of the array and zero if there are no elements in the array.

The `.Length` property *is* an integer, so there's no need for any conversion. Though there's really no need to assign it because it is a constant-time operation, you could assign it like this:

```
int arrayLength = array.Length;
```

[Array.Length on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx)